# Настройка ssh туннеля для получения доступа к интернету

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, ssh, socks5

Есть две vm под управлением ubuntu 20. Обе находятся в одной подсети, одном vlan. Одна имеет доступ в интернет другая нет. К обеим виртуалкам у меня рут доступ. Мне надо обновить вторую виртуалку. Для этого я использую данную команду для создания ssh туннеля:  `ssh -N -D 9090 [USER]@[SERVER_IP]`.

После ввода команды предлагает ввести пароль. Я его ввожу и пустая строка. Подскажите что делать?

> я не линуксоид, а только учусь, но деньги позволяют мне делать любые чудеса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На всякий случай уточню: эту команду нужно запускать на виртуалке без интернета и в `SERVER_IP` указывать ту, где он есть.

То что ничего не происходит это правильно, команда запущена и слушает на локальном порту 9090 и готова проксировать соединения через SOCKS на `SERVER_IP`.

Теперь осталось воспользоваться этим на той виртуалке, на которой нет интернета. Для этого нужно `apt` указать чтоб он использовал прокси.

Oтредактируйте файл (создайте если его нет) `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf` и добавьте строку:

```
Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks5h://localhost:9090";
```